# MLR: makes sense if the dependent variable is constant?

Tags: multiple-regression

my general MLR-model looks like:
\begin{equation}
y=\beta_0*predictor_1+\beta_1*predictor_2+\epsilon
\end{equation}
The problem is, that y is in all measurements constant.

Does this method is still suitable if y is constant?
Or am I totally wrong and another method would be the right one?

*Background*: y is the energy level of a battery (only known, when the battery is newly inserted into the device). At the end of the battery's life, only the values of predictor1 and predictor2 are known. The goal is to calculate the coefficients to get to know, how much influence the predictors have on the energy level y. Knowing this, an interpolation should be possible to calculate the actual energy level.

Comment: How was y measured?

Answer (score 1):

In general if the response or outcome variable, dependent variable $y$ in your terminology and notation, is constant, then there is no variation to explain and statistics has little or nothing to contribute.

I am going to rewrite your equation as $y=\beta_1*predictor_1+\beta_2*predictor_2+\epsilon$

as your notation is, frankly, only likely to confuse.

In your case the outcome is constant regardless of the values of the predictors; so there can be no dependence on either predictor, and the coefficients $\beta_1, \beta_2$ are necessarily zero. So your model collapses to saying that the variation is just equivalent to the error term, and the error term is identical to the mean or constant value.

A more conventional model would include an intercept $\beta_0$ (once more, my notation differs in this detail from that in your question). There usually has to be a special reason for omitting an intercept, namely that it is known that the response must be zero if the predictors are zero. Hence with an intercept

$y=\beta_0 + \beta_1*predictor_1+\beta_2*predictor_2+\epsilon$

With this formula the wording changes, but (given no variation in $y$) the model collapses to $y \equiv \beta_0$ and so the constant and also mean value $y$ and the intercept $\beta_0$ are identical. The error term, if anyone wants to spell it out, is just constant at zero.

(You have sketched the physical or engineering background to what you are doing, but I am afraid that it doesn't reduce my puzzlement at your question. Whichever way you look at it, if the response is constant, only a constant can be identified on the other side of the equation. I think there is likely to be some elementary confusion here at some level. If you have measurements **that vary** of the initial energy level then naturally you can try to model such variation as a function of your predictors and at first sight that is a standard regression problem.)